# VB.Net How do you move the focus to the entry text box when the user selects a different item in a combo box?

Tags: vb.net

How do you move the focus to the entry text box everytime the user selects a different item in a combo box?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't find an answer on the net.

Comment: try this  textbox.focus()

Comment: Didn't work. I've tried textbox.focus () & textbox.Select() but they don't focus when i click on items from the combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the combo box selected index changed event ; use

```
textbox1.Select()
```

or

```
textbox1.Focus
```